# Specify destination folders outside of Drupal root using Drush Make

Tags: 7, drush

Is there a way to configure Drush Make so that it would build a structure like:

project_root

- drupal_core
- drupal_contrib

So that next in the build process (that this would form a part of) could symlink the sites/all directory to drupal_contrib

It would be set up this way as I would prefer the build process to allow an upgrade of Drupal core by simply removing sylinks, upgrading, then re-adding symlinks

I'm aware the build process might as well just loop through some drush dl x statements, or that if Drush Make was used the folders could easily be re-jigged afterwards. Just interested if there is a non-hacky way of doing it first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed how I can get part of the way there without moving the downloaded files around

From my main directory I can run

```
drush make --no-core --contrib-destination=modules test.make sites
```

to yield

```
project_name
  - sites
    - modules
    - themes
```

then use a standard

```
drush dl
```

to get core and then use custom scripts to symlink core/sites/all -> project_name/sites or something like that.

There doesn't seem to be an option for --no-contrib or anything like that (probably because there isn't much point)